# Upgrade Civi to 5.67 failed

Tags: upgrade

When trying to upgrade CiviCRM from 5.58.1 to 5.67.0 fails with

```
1265                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  ALTER TABLE `civicrm_note` CHANGE `privacy` `privacy` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'Foreign Key to Note Privacy Level (which is an option value pair and hence an implicit FK)' [nativecode=1265 ** Data truncated for column   
  'privacy' at row 2018]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try updating the database with below query

```
UPDATE civicrm_note
SET privacy = 0
WHERE privacy IS NULL;
```